# python 2.4 sorting a text file by specific column

Tags: python, csv

Completely new to python i'm having problems finding this with version 2.4

I have a text file that contains 3 columns they are tab delimited by not a single tab, 9 tabs. 
1000 line file
ex:

```
$1$sda4356:[sgb1_diska5.ldlbat44.libabl]talild_0329_base.rpt                                talild_0329_base.rpt                                                                      00000000000000005062
```

What i need to do is sort everything by column 3 ( 00000000000000005062 ).

Is using the csv reader the best way to handle doing this?  how do i get it to handle the fact that my text file is using 9 tabs to seperate each column. Most other things i'm finding are incompatiable with python 2.4.

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you reading in the file, or are you stuck on that delimiter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using 9 tabs, `str.split` seems like it should be able to handle this properly, (but I don't see any reason why `csv` would choke on it ...):

```
fobj = open('data.csv')
data = [ x.split() for x in fobj ]
fobj.close()  #don't forget to close :)
```

Or possibly:

```
delim = '\t'*9
data = [ x.split(delim) for x in fobj ]
```

Then you can sort that.  In a newer version of python, you'd do:

```
from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
```

Try this first!  (According to the comments and the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), `key` is supported in python2.4, but not python2.3).  [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is also "new in python2.4" and `itemgetter(2)` is equivalent to `lambda x:x[2]` or the more verbose:

```
def get2(x):
    return x[2]
```

---

But I think you might need to rely on `cmp` for compatability with really old python versions (Note, that python3 no longer supports `cmp`):

```
def compare(x1,x2):
    if x1[2] > x2[2]:
       return 1
    elif x1[2] < x2[2]:
       return -1
    else:
       return 0
```

and then you'd sort:

```
data.sort(cmp=compare)
```

Comment: Python 2.4 supports `key`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Found the documentation to prove your assertion.  python2.4 does in fact support `key`, but python2.3 doesn't.  Thanks for pointing this out.  (It seems like a lot of good things happened in python2.4 ...)

Comment: `fobj = open('data.csv')
data = [ x.split() for x in fobj ]
fobj.close()

from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(2))

def get2(x):
        return x[2]

def compare(x1,x2):
        if x1[2] > x2[2]:
                return 1
        elif x1[2] < x2[2]:
                return -1
        else:
                return 0

data.sort(cmp=compare)`

What am i doing wrong ?  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in ?
    data.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
IndexError: list index out of range

Thanks!

Comment: tried both ways with the `from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(2))` and `def compare(x1,x2):
    if x1[2] > x2[2]:
       return 1
    elif x1[2] < x2[2]:
       return -1
    else:
       return 0`  both give me the same error  i think i'm missing something with the x.split maybe.. IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: you probably have a line with only one column to see which do `for d in data:if len(d) <2:print(d)`

Comment: Problem is with the layout of the txt file i have, because it already contains brackets [] i think this is causing the problem.  The answer provided worked fine with a test file i created.  Thanks

Comment: 2 lines at the end of the csv file caused the problem not the brackets. Code worked perfectly!  here is what i used, i reversed the sort so the higher numbers are on top.
`fobj = open('data.csv')
data = [ x.split() for x in fobj ]
fobj.close()

from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)`